# How can I force a ReflectionTypeLoadException?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to test an assembly extension method which is basically a wrapper around `Assembly.GetTypes()` which handles cases when a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` is thrown because for whatever reason one or more Types in the loaded Assembly could not be loaded.

I have tried explicitly throwing `TypeLoadExceptions` from the static & instance constructors, and also trying to instantiate an instance of this dummy class and calling the `DoStuff()` method to break it before trying to load the types, but `Assembly.GetTypes()` is always returning the Type and not throwing an `ReflectionTypeLoadException`.

How can I force this behaviour?

```
    public class WillNotInitiliase
    {
        public WillNotInitiliase()
        {
            BreakType();
        }

       static WillNotInitiliase()
       {
           BreakType();
       }

       public static  void DoStuff()
       {
       }

       private static void BreakType() => throw new TypeLoadException( "I can never be loaded" );
    }
```

Comment: If the type is there then you can get the type and remember type != instance of type

Comment: Declare an `extern` method in the type but do not provide any attribute for its implementation (`DllImport`). On loading such a type, a `TypeLoadException` is triggered.